# Are these proofs correct?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

I haven't formally learn how to do proofs, but I attempted some of these. It'd be great if you guys can check them and give me some pointers.  Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Consider using latex for your posts.

Answer (score 0):

All of them look ok, maybe for the one below it would be easier $|x-y|=|x+(-y)|\leq|x|+|-y|=|x|+|y|$.

And for the reversed triangle inequality you could also apply the triangle inequality $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$ with $a=x-y,b=y$.